# How can I relate multiple tables (as sub-fields) to one table (as main field) in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

[image]
I'm a novice user of Microsoft Access and all I wanna do is linking multiple tables to one table as a child-parent relation. I've set tables and I can make one relation, but when I'm trying to set another table as a child input, misconfiguration appears. I've uploaded the relation pattern screen. I would be greatly appreciated if you can tell me whats wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by 'misconfiguration'? What you have looks fine.

Comment: I can only have one table as sub-field or child, if I add the second table it seems I have to choose only one table as child.

Comment: That is correct for datasheet and subdatasheet - so use form/subforms in single/continuous view.